# Mouse Profile not changing on G Hub automatically

Tags: technical-issues, mouse, roblox, logitech-g-hub

I made a profile for roblox, with lower sensitivity than my normal profile (which I named "normal work"). Now when I launch Roblox then g hub does not auto switch to Roblox profile (and the profile's selected app is RobloxPlayerBeta.exe, and even in task manager when I open file location for Roblox process, I get RobloxPlayerBeta.exe). I have a g102 lightspeed mouse.

PS: the profile does auto switch to my normal work profile when I close Roblox.

Comment: I'm not sure how the profile won't switch to Roblox, but magically switches back to your normal when it closes? Are you manually changing the profile when you launch Roblox, and observing it automatically return to the normal profile when exiting the game?

Comment: yes @nightsurfer , i manually change to roblox profile after starting roblox, then it auto changes to default normal work profile when i close roblox

Comment: @Devyansh you likely have competing versions of roblox on your system - roblox creates a new folder (and new executable) for RobloxPlayerBeta.exe every update, and if it isn't pointed to the correct one, logitech won't detect that that *specific* RobloxPlayerBeta.exe is open. This does assume that logitech matches file location and not window title.